# MySQL JSON extract values only if there value > 1

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
+-------------+----------------+
| id          |  server        |
+-------------+----------------+
| 1           |  ["1", "15"]   |
+-------------+----------------+
```

I need to get only value that is grather that 1 so in above example i need to get from output only 15

I try using this:

```
SELECT
JSON_EXTRACT(server, "$[*]") as server
FROM streams
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(server, "$[*]") != JSON_QUOTE('1')
AND id=1;
```

But i always get ["1", "15"] and need to get ["15"].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 
JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(server, 'all', 1)) IS NULL THEN 
    JSON_REMOVE(server, '$."1"')
ELSE 
    JSON_REMOVE(server, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(server, 'one', 1)))
END AS server
FROM streams WHERE id=2 AND server NOT LIKE '%[]%';
```

Now it works but if ["1"] is only 1 in json column i get []...a added `NOT LIKE '%[]%'` but it prints out always []...where i need to add to get no results found from mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do this with MySQL's `JSON_EXTRACT` and `JSON_SEARCH` functions as they perform extraction and exact matching (not comparison) respectively. So, you have two options:

- Normalise the table and have `server` values into a new column (recommended)
- Fetch all the values and perform the filtering in service layer